# Python: Why is the __len__() of a sequence ignored when iterating?

Tags: python, loops, sequence

I'd like to create a custom sequence of elements. When iterating over it, the length of the sequence is ignored. Here is a minimal code example:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __len__(self):
        return 5

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return idx

t = Test()
for i, x in enumerate(t):
    print(i, x)
```

I'd expect to have only `0 0` to `4 4` printed out. In reality, the loop behaves as with an infinitely long sequence and goes on and on and on. `len(t)` returns `5` as expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python expects `__getitem__()` to raise an `IndexError` when indexes outside of the possible range are requested, as noted in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

> **Note** `for` loops expect that an `IndexError` will be raised for illegal indexes to allow proper detection of the end of the sequence.

The advantage to this is that you don't *have* to implement `__len__()` which means your index-based iterable can be lazy, meaning unknown lengths or infinite lengths are possible.

This mirrors the way [iterator objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) and for loops work in Python - they continue to ask for values until an exception is reached (`StopIteration` for iterators), which makes the implementation easier - `iter()` just wraps with a loop incrementing the index until it hits the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check yourself, if the key is out of bounds. `__len__` is only used for two purposes. To be able to call len(obj) and it will be used, if no `__bool__` method exists to determine, if the object evaluates to true in conditions.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how to solve the issue - "you have to check yourself", and then do what with that information?